# Object creation when assigning default parameter value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

The follow compiles and runs but the value of file is always nil. Does this mean you simply can not perform object creation as part of defining a default parameter value?

```
public func trace(message: String, 
                 var file: NSURL! = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(__FILE__), 
                 function: String = __FUNCTION__) {

    let context = NBContext(file: file, function: function)
    self.note(message, level: .Trace, context: context)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that __FILE__ is a valid file? `fileURLWithPath` returns an Optional, so it is possible that the file is simply invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating an object is possible, because if you replace `__FILE__` with a valid path to a file it works as expected. It looks like it's something about `__FILE__`.

I tested on a project, and this is what I found out:

- `__FILE__` as raw default value works
- `String(__FILE__)` does **not** work
- `"" + __FILE__` does **not** work
- `var file: NSURL! = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("<actual-path-of-the-current-file>")` works

I can test other variations, but I expect all of them to fail when using `__FILE__`

So the conclusion is that you can assign it as a default value, but you have to use it as a raw string and not in expressions of any type. As for the *why*, at this moment I have no idea (suggestions are welcome)

However I think your function has a bug: it's possible to pass `nil` for the `file` parameter - I presume you don't want that to happen. A better approach is:

```
public func trace(message: String, var file: NSURL? = nil, function: String = __FUNCTION__) {
    if file == nil {
        file = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(__FILE__)
    }

    let context = NBContext(file: file, function: function)
    self.note(message, level: .Trace, context: context)
}
```

**Addendum**: this is the code I've used for testing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        test()
    }

    func test() {
        let x = NBContext(file: nil)
        println(x)
    }
}

public class NBContext: Printable {

    let file: NSURL?
    let function: String
    let line: Int
    let time: NSDate

    init (file: NSURL?, function: String = __FUNCTION__, line: Int = __LINE__, time: NSDate = NSDate.date()) {           
        self.file = file
        self.function = function
        self.line = line
        self.time = time
    }

    public var description: String {
        return "\(time) > " + file!.lastPathComponent + " " + function + ":\(line)"
    }
}
```

and this is the content of `x`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great reply! You say in your first finding that __FILE__ as raw default value works. I'm surprised by that, because if I use any of the constants, E.G __FUNCTION__, they don't work.If you look at the Gist in the following link, those default parameter values are all "" inside the init() https://gist.github.com/rayascott/9de5e3805169f7275603

Comment: I tried that code, and something is wrong indeed. The only difference I see is that you're using a `struct`. I changed it to a `class`, and it seems to work. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I changed my struct to a class and it didn't help. Perhaps it's returning "" for __FUNCTION__ because it's part of the function signature and not truly inside a function? It's also returning 0 for __LINE__. I was hoping that by invoking func error(message: String, context: NBContext = NBContext()) {} I could get the values from the call site, but I think that's asking too much.

Comment: Yup. What values are returned when it works as a default parameter? Source file line number and the function name that it's a default parameter of?